# A better way to do conditional ActiveRecord statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out a better way to have one query here. I want to be able to send something to last where statement a wildcard so I can select all vendors. Right now if i don't include that line it doesn't filter by vendor so I essentially get all the purchase requests.

Any thoughts of a cleaner way to do these sorts of queries?

```
  if @vendor == "0" #checks for vendor
    @purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order)
                          .where(:created_at => @date_start..@date_end)
                          .where(:total_cost => @cost_beginning..@cost_end)
  else
    @purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order)
                          .where(:created_at => @date_start..@date_end)
                          .where(:total_cost => @cost_beginning..@cost_end)
                          .where("purchaseorder.VendorRef_ListID = ?", @vendor)
  end
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about refactoring working code are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll repost there, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there must be some better solution, but try this

```
@purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order).where(created_at: @date_start..@date_end, total_cost: @cost_beginning..@cost_end)
@purchase_requests = @purchase_requests.where("purchaseorder.VendorRef_ListID = ?", @vendor) unless @vendor == "0"
```

Comment: First three lines can be written in a single line. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version:

```
@purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest
                     .includes(:purchase_order)
                     .where(created_at: @date_start..@date_end)
                     .where(total_cost: @cost_beginning..@cost_end)
@purchase_requests = @purchase_requests.where('purchase_orders.VendorRef_ListID = ?', @vendor) unless @vendor == '0'
```